# How Can I Change My tkinter icon with these few lines of code?

Tags: tkinter, python-3.6

I have seen other posts about this question and did not understand fully as to what was going on.
these are the few lines of code (my .ico file is in the same folder as my script)

```
icon = PhotoImage(file='panther.ico')
root.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', root._w, icon)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ronald\Desktop\New folder\Longwood Math Game.py", line 158, in <module>
    icon = PhotoImage(file='panther.ico')
  File "C:\Users\ronald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\ronald\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3495, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "panther.ico"
```

KEEP IN MIND MY .ICO FILE IS LOCATED IN THE SAME FOLDER AS MY SOURCE CODE

Comment: Provide us a link to the image in question in order to see what is wrong

Comment: `PhotoImage` works only with .gif and .pgm. Other formats need `PIL` module. See [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
root.iconbitmap('panther.ico')
```

would be the better option in my code because the 'PhotoImage' doesnt support my ico file